# Failing to create a random access stream around URI

Tags: c#, xaml

Error:

> Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image doesn't contain a definition for 'AbsoluteUri'

in xaml.cs page

```
var refernce = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(image1.AbsoluteUri));
```

in .xaml page

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Height="300" Stretch="UniformToFill">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is that it'll probably work if you reference image1.Source:

```
var refernce = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(image1.Source));
```

Since the Source is bound to a property called "ImagePath", that's likely to be the path to the image you're looking for. If the image is rendering properly, then you're probably good.

Comment: No, its an invalid argument. Any other way?

Comment: Try a ToString() on the Source? image1.Source.ToString() Or examine the image1.Source for a relevant property that will give the Url.